# How to deal with a value that might be an array, or might be only a single item react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and am trying to make a user survey, in this Component I am working with checkboxes which I find a little tricky. I want the user to choose 2 options and then put a comma between the two chosen options, how can I do that?

Earlier I used stageArtCategory.join(', ') in my Summary.js component but that broke the rendering of Summary in case the user chose only one instead of two options...

CODE:

```
import React from 'react';

import NextQuestionButton from './NextQuestionButton'
import Popup from './Popup'

const QuestionStageArtCheckbox = ({
    stageArtCategory,
  setStageArtCategory,
  page,
  setPage,
  onNextQuestion
}) => {
  const onStageArtChange = (stageArtValue) => {
    if (stageArtCategory.includes(stageArtValue)) {
      setStageArtCategory(stageArtCategory.filter((item) => item !== stageArtValue))
    } else {
      setStageArtCategory([...stageArtCategory, stageArtValue])
    } 
  }
    
  const stageartGroup = [
    "I'm for experimental shit, I need to see something I can not immediately understand", 
    "I want to dance with my kid", 
    "Opera", 
    "Theatre", 
    "Musical", 
    "Concert",
    "I just miss the feeling of collectivity, and long to be able to see something with another person's eye - just once, please!", 
    "I want to drink beer with my friends after a show"
  ]

  return (
    <article className="form-question-3">
      {/* Q */}
      <p className="form-question" tabIndex="0">
        What kind of stage art would you like too experience post Covid-19? Pick 2 as they are made to overlap a little! <span role="img" aria-label="smiling emoji with one eye blinking"></span>
      </p>

      {/* A */}
      <div className="question-content-container-3">
        {stageartGroup.map((stagearts) => (
          <span className="form-checkbox-question-container" key={stagearts}>
            <label className="checkbox-label" htmlFor={stagearts}>{stagearts}</label>
            <input
              id={stagearts}
              type="checkbox"
              className="form-checkbox"
              checked={stageArtCategory.includes(stagearts)}
              onChange={() => onStageArtChange(stagearts)}
            />
          </span>
        ))}
          <div className="buttons-container-3">
            <NextQuestionButton
              page={page}
              setPage={setPage}
              currentState={stageArtCategory.length}
              defaultState={0}
              message="Please choose what kind of overlapping stage arts you would like to experience first!"
              onClick={onNextQuestion}
              button="Next question button"
              buttontext="Next question"
            />
          </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default QuestionStageArtCheckbox
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. So, I've had a good read through the code, and it looks like this should always return an array. Perhaps what you're seeing is that it's being initialised as null or undefined, so your stageArtCategory.join(', ') in Summary is attempting to call "join" on something that doesn't have that method?

If you try ```(stageArtCategory || []).join(', ')``` in Summary does that fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you for a very useful answer. I added the useState in my Form.js to be            
const [stageArtCategory, setStageArtCategory] = useState([]) and then it worked to have only stageArtCategory.join(', ') as well but I've added yours for clarification.

Comment: Great! Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialised the useState as an empty string earlier but changed it to be an empty array. This solved the problem.

```
const [stageArtCategory, setStageArtCategory] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to always treat such values as an arrays. So, whenever I need to use such value, I turn it into array with `.concat` method.

```js
function arbitraryFunction(arrayOrSingle) {
  let array = [].concat(arrayOrSingle);
  // do something with array
}
```